# cb range problem

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to ask you about an advice in some specific problem with pgfplots routine. I tried to search any information on the internet, however with no satisfy reasults and that is the reason, why I am asking about the help.

My problem is as follow:

I ploted 3D surface plot with view as map (bellow is the example and code),

in "colorbar style" function I setup some cb settings,

picture is plotted via gnuplot external software,

because I need to setup the cb range for all (#hundreds) plots in the same range, I used point meta min/max, etc.

HOWEVER, the cb range does not correspond with real plotted situation on the presented picture. How to fix that problem?

Thank you in advance for your help, Michal.

### data:

```
X  Y  Z  2013-01-01 00:00:00
48.0000  15.0000    2.1759    2.1859  =>  -0.0100 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0723
49.0000  14.0000    2.2063    2.2063  =>  -0.0000 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0418 
49.0000  15.0000    2.2133    2.2177  =>  -0.0043 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0348 
49.0000  16.0000    2.2542    2.2289  =>  0.0253 ** 2.2481 ==> 0.0061 
50.0000  13.0000    2.2175    2.2261  =>  -0.0087 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0306 
50.0000  14.0000    2.2427    2.2375  =>  0.0052 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0055
50.0000  15.0000    2.2540    2.2488  =>  0.0052 ** 2.2481 ==> 0.0059
50.0000  16.0000    2.2468    2.2601  =>  -0.0133 ** 2.2481 ==> -0.0013
51.0000  14.0000    2.2808    2.2680  =>  0.0127 ** 2.2481 ==> 0.0326
51.0000  15.0000    2.2788    2.2793  =>  -0.0006 ** 2.2481 ==> 0.0306
51.0000  16.0000    2.2791    2.2906  =>  -0.0115 ** 2.2481 ==> 0.0310
```

### code:

For example, the plotted value at the point [16,49] (showed in the fig) in real situation is characterised by ± 0.025, however according to presented cb range, its value is ± 0.06 ... And that is what I want to fix. I also tried to setup cbrange[-0.06:0.06] as gnuplot function, but that does not work as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.5, colormap/cool}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=test/]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{test0}

\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
  view={0}{90},
  title={$\textsc{\LARGE{GOPE 2013-01-01 00:00:00}}$},
  xlabel=$\textsc{Longitude [\textdegree]}$,
  ylabel=$\textsc{Latitude [\textdegree]}$,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel style={sloped},
  xlabel style={sloped},
  xtick={13,14,15,16},
  ytick={48,49,50,51},
  colorbar,
  every colorbar/.append style={
  point meta min = -0.06,
  point meta max = 0.06,
  /pgf/number format/fixed,
  ylabel={\normalsize{Differences of input data and fitted regression plane\ [m]}},
  }
]%

\addplot3 [surf] gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{
set dgrid3d 50,50 spline;
splot '2013-1-0' u 2:1:6;
 };
\addplot3 [only marks, mark=*, mark size=3pt] table[x index=1, y index=0] {2013-1-0};
\addplot [only marks, mark=oplus, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(14.7, 49.9)}; % GOPE

\legend{ ,Fitted Grid Nodes, Receiver}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### FIG

[image: example]

### edit

Hi, 
Thanks for the answer and I just add my comment. In my opinion, data are correct and gnuplot as well. If I made a comment:

```
%   every colorbar/.append style={
%   point meta min = -0.06,
%   point meta max =  0.06,
%   /pgf/number format/fixed,
%   ylabel={\normalsize{Differences of input data and fitted regression plane\     [m]}},
%   }
```

I get the colorbas as can be expected. But, what I need is to unify the range of all colorbars. For example, on fig. 3, you can see the range +/- [-0.03:0.025] and first two pics have [-0.02:0.025]. And I need the same one and of course the plots have to correspond to z-values of real data (6-th column in input file, as was showed above).

### Fig 1

[image: Figure 1]

### Fig 2

[image: Figure 2]

### Fig 3

[image: Figure 3]

### Fig 4

[image]

Comment: Please try to minimize your problem to the possible minimum! If possible, use `filecontents` and leave out the use of `gnuplot` (speaking of your MWE here). The point [16,49] is written as 0.0061 in your data file. But you want it to be +-0.025. The problem would be in your data or your gnuplot calculation then and therefore off-topic here. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi LaRiFaRi, please see my add comment!

Answer (score 3):

The root cause for the inconsistency between colorbar and surface plot is that "point meta min" and "point meta max" are only specified within the color bar style, but not for the axis as such. The effect is that the colorbar's axis descriptions are overwritten, but the surface plot is entirely unaware of the modification.

I do not know if the possibility to cause such inconsistencies is a bug or a feature in pgfplots - the intention behind such modifications is to allow full customization of the colorbar's axis descriptions.

Anyway, the solution is to move "point meta min" and "point meta max" into the set of normal axis options, i.e.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.5, colormap/cool}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
  view={0}{90},
  xlabel={$\textsc{Longitude}$},
  ylabel={$\textsc{Latitude}$},
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel style={sloped},
  xlabel style={sloped},
  xtick={13,14,15,16},
  ytick={48,49,50,51},
  colorbar,
  point meta min = -0.06,
  point meta max = 0.06,
  every colorbar/.append style={
      /pgf/number format/fixed,
      ylabel={\normalsize{Differences of input data and fitted regression plane\ [m]}},
  }
]%

\addplot3 [surf] gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{
set dgrid3d 50,50 spline;
splot '2013-1-0' u 2:1:6;
 };
\addplot3 [only marks, mark=*, mark size=3pt] table[x index=1, y index=0] {2013-1-0};
\addplot [only marks, mark=oplus, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(14.7, 49.9)}; % GOPE

\legend{ ,Fitted Grid Nodes, Receiver}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will result in consistent color codings ( by changing the appearance of the surface plot dramatically):

[image]